# Why is the maximum value of an orthonormal dictionary of size $N \times N$ less than that of another having size $M \times M$, where M>N?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

I was trying to compare the maximum value in DCT dictionary (representing an orthonormal dictionary) of size $N \times N$ to that of another DCT dictionary of size $M \times M$, where $M>N$. I always found that the highest value of $DCT_{M \times M} > DCT_{N \times N}$? Is there any mathematical reason behind it? Can this be generalized for all orthonormal dictionaries?

Comment: It might help if you say what "orthonormal dictionary " means, and what its "value" is.  These are not  standard terms.

Comment: I meant, the orthogonality property should be maintained. So, $AA^T=A^TA=I$. A good example might be discrete cosine transform, Gabor frame etc.